# How to render React component only on click

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and I'm still having issues understanding how some of the things work. I have the following code:

```
var Table = React.createClass({
    render: function render() {
        var _self = this;
        var thead = this.props.cols.map(function (col) {
                    return React.DOM.th({}, col);
            }
        var tbody = this.props.rows.map(function (row) {
                .....
        });
        return React.DOM.table({className:'table-striped'}, [thead, tbody]);
    }
});

<script type="text/babel">
var tableModel = {
    cols: ["head1", "head2"],
    rows: [
        {"head1": "content1", "head2": "content2"},
    ],
}

React.render(React.createElement(Table,tableModel), document.getElementById('id'));
</script>
```

It works great, it generates a table. I can't, however, for the life of me, find how to do this **only** when a certain link is pressed. So on my page i have a normal link and I only want the above to be generated when that button is pressed. 
How can that be done? I've been searching for several good minutes but it just looks like nobody else is trying to achieve something similar.

Comment: Just move `React.render(....)` into the click event handler of the link?

Comment: I tried and I get that tableModel is not defined

Comment: Without having a complete picture it's impossible to say what you are doing wrong. All I can say is that `tableModel` must be in scope of the event handle.

Comment: Well, I'll put it on the account of being tired, but I found the issue. It seems that the variables inside a babel script are only available in that local scope. If I replace the babel script with a javascript script, the tableModel variable is seen. So if you have a var inside a <script type="text/babel"> it's not seen outside of it.

Comment: Ah yeah, it could be that Babel treats each `<script>` similar to a module and creates a separate scope it.

Answer (score 0):

It's embarrassing, but I found the issue. Following does not work:

```
<script type="text/babel">
var tableModel = {..}
</script>       
<button onClick="React.render(React.createElement(Table,tableModel), document.getElementById('open_request_list_content'));">click</button>
```

while the following (only *script type* differs) does work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableModel = {..}
</script>       
<button onClick="React.render(React.createElement(Table,tableModel), document.getElementById('open_request_list_content'));">click</button>
```

I guess there are still things to learn about babel...

Comment: `React.render` is deprecated. Use `ReactDOM.render` instead